# packages installed with Yarn start to give error like sweetalert2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, yarnpkg

I am working on rails 6.
couple of hours back I added sweetalert2 with yarn like

```
yarn add sweetalert2
```

and than imported it like

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
```

it was working fine and than I switched github branch & when came back to original branch,
it started to give error like

> Cannot find module 'sweetalert2'

not sure if missed something or what happened.

**UPDATE**

I did `yarn install` but it says already up to date & same issue still exist.

```
yarn install v1.21.1
warning ../package.json: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.76s.
```

Answer (score 0):

For sure, when you switch the branch, you can retry with **npm install** and **yarn** command as the code base has been changed/switched.

Try running `yarn` and `npm install` again.

Comment: I did but  yarn install but same issue, updated my question with response